# Hyperparameter tuning for SGDClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, hyperparameters

My dataset consists of 3 sets: training, validation and test data. I ran the following code on the training set, followed by the validation set.

```
#model for SVM with BOW
sgd_1 = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
               ])

#time to train the model
stsgd_1 = time.time()

sgd_1.fit(x_train, y_train)

print("time to train the model", (time.time() - stsgd_1))

ypred_sgd1 = sgd_1.predict(x_val)

print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(ypred_sgd1, y_val))
print(classification_report(y_val, ypred_sgd1,target_names=my_tags))

cf_matrix_sgd = confusion_matrix(y_val, ypred_sgd1)
print_confusion_matrix(cf_matrix_sgd, my_tags)
```

I was able to achieve an accuracy level of 90.15%.
Then I did the hyperparameter tuning using the following code.

```
#tuning both BOW and sgd resulted in lowering the accuracy
    param_sgd1 = {
        "vect__max_df": (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
        'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
        "vect__ngram_range": ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
        "clf__alpha": (0.00001, 0.000001),
        "clf__penalty": ("l2", "elasticnet"),
        'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80),
    }
    
    gs_sgd1 = GridSearchCV(sgd_1, param_sgd1, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
    
    print("performing grid search on SVM")
    print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in sgd_1.steps])
    print("parameters:")
    pprint(param_sgd1)
    #t0 = time()
    gs_sgd1.fit(x_val, y_val)
    #print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print()
    
    print("Best score: %0.3f" % gs_sgd1.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters set:")
    best_parameters = gs_sgd1.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(param_sgd1.keys()):
        print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

This generated the following output
[image]

Then I ran the model again with the tuned hyperparameter values as follows.

```
#Refit the model for SVM with tuned hyperparameters
sgd_final1 = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(max_df=1.0, max_features=5000, ngram_range=(1,1))),
                ('clf', SGDClassifier(alpha=1e-05, max_iter=80, penalty="elasticnet")),
               ])
```

I fitted this on the same validation set to compare with the previous values. But this time, the accuracy is decreased and the time taken to train the model also has been increased.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: You're not including the default values in your grid search, and you're finding the defaults are better than what you used. e.g. the default value of max_iter in SGDClassifier is 1000, but you only test values up to 80. Also, whenever you find that grid search prefers the extreme value for a parameter, you should think about adding more values of that parameter in that directory. The grid search preferred extreme values for max_iter and alpha, so you should think about adding higher max_iter and higher alpha to the grid search.

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut I'll post this in the relevant site

Comment: Thank you @Nick ODell for your input. I'll try that.